# how to safely destroy a mutex using pthread_mutex_destroy

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads, mutex

I have a class that wraps some logic and has a worker thread, there are several functions that   that check the status of the work done so far.
I wrap the changes to the inner data and the checks using a mutex, api requires that there'd be a signal function that tells the class to begin shutting down, meaning no new requests can be handles but as long as the old ones are still on progress, it's OK to check their status.

My problem is that I'm having hard time deciding when to safely destroy the mutex, because the moment I unlock it, there might be another thread that tries to check the status of some job and I'll end up destroying a locked mutex which is bad.
Any suggestions?

- **EDIT:** Could this work?
  ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE)
   {
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&om);
     pthread_mutex_destroy(&om);
   }
  (using the macro from asm/atomic.h) *

Shouldn't be used as it seems...

**EDIT2:**

Suppose I had the following functions:

```
void queue_image(image pic){
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mo);
     // add 
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mo);
}

void is_pic_processed(string pic_id){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mo);
     // chech whether pic was processed
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mo);
}

void * process(void* arg){ //this is in another thread
    while(1){
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mo);
      if(kill_flag && no more work){ 
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&mo);
(1)      /* the problem is here because in the meanwhile 
            someone could've called is_pic_processed locked the mutex 
            and now I'm destroying a locked mutex which is undesirable */
         pthread_mutex_destroy(&mo);
      }
      // do more work 
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mo);
    }
}

void kill(){ // has to return and not wait for the remaining processing to take place
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mo);
     // set flag to end the work 
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mo);
}
```

The kill is to only stop processing and not the entire application, I have no problem with other threads calling is_pic_processed *after* the destruction of the mutex and getting an appropriate error I have a problem with them being called while trying to destroy the mutex in the first place, hope this clears the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question. You should not destroy the mutex as long as there are still "on progress" requests.

The worker thread itself should check the request queue and if the "shutdown" function has been called it should destroy the mutex and, presumably, die.

So:

- No one will try to lock the mutex because all requests have been handled and there are no requests in progress
- It is safe to destroy a locked mutex as soon as it is the same thread which locks it and destroys it

Hope I correctly understood the question :)

**After your Edit 2**

What you added conflicts with a thing you said before:

> as long as the old ones are still on progress, it's OK to check their status.

You are now saying that their status can be checked even after they're no more "on progress".

Anyway this is not a problem. Because you can call `pthread_mutex_destroy` **without** calling `pthread_mutex_unlock` before.

I used this as a source [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7 - pthread.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html)

**Edit 3**: 
I'd like to add something to my answer: you need a bit of redesign here.

Even if you can destroy that mutex while it is locked, you need to make sure that no other thread can try to lock it after it has been destroyed for example by checking the status of your now-completed requets.

In other words, if you want to destroy the mutex then it must not be possible to check the status of the requests using the mutex after the "kill flag" has been set.

Comment: hi,thanks for the answer, I've tried to better explain the situation.

Comment: @SadStudent if that's why you voted -1, please reconsider.

You quoted it yourself: **by another thread**.

If he **does not unlock** it, he **can destroy it safely**.
Notice that he is locking that mutex right at the beginning of the infinite loop, therefore it **cannot** be locked when he calls pthread_mutex_destroy if he does not lock it before, as I suggested.

Comment: it seems that this is not correct, because I'm getting the same error as in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118606