# what is the correct behavior of pthread_mutex_destroy when destroying a locked mutex

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I wrote the following minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <pthread.h>
#define SUCCESS 0
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int res;
    pthread_mutex_t t;
    pthread_mutex_init(&t, NULL);

    res = pthread_mutex_lock(&t);

    res = pthread_mutex_destroy(&t);
    if (res != SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "Failed to delete: " << strerror(res) << " # " << t.__data.__lock << " " << t.__data.__nusers << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Deleted!"<< endl;
    }

    res = pthread_mutex_unlock(&t);
    cout << res << endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;

}
```

Also at [ideone](http://ideone.com/QLs2fc)

On one side as someone noted, [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html) apparently says

> Attempting to destroy a locked mutex or a mutex that is referenced (for example, while being used in a pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait()) **by another thread** results in undefined behavior.

So one could assume that if it **the same thread** then it's OK.

It's odd because this sentence was changed in the older version it was not there and the line said only

> It shall be safe to destroy an initialized mutex that is unlocked. Attempting to destroy a locked mutex results in undefined behavior.

So it's not that far fetched to think that this change was made for a reason, I'm just trying to be sure.

I tested the previously mentioned code on two different linux systems(ubuntu 13.10 and another debian 5774) and it fails and prints "Failed to delete: Device or resource busy # 1 1" , where on ideone's platform it succeeds.

Is ideones' behavior is just a specific case of undefined behavior? Or is there something wrong with the other cases?

Unfortunately I couldn't find a source that specifically addresses this issue.

Comment: As the text mentions, it is an `Undefined Behaviour`.

Comment: @brokenfoot yes but is it just in the case it is done by another thread or not? I've tried to clarify why would some one think this would matter.

Comment: Just stick to Posix specification. It is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quoted text:

> Attempting to destroy a locked mutex or a mutex that is referenced (for example, while being used in a `pthread_cond_timedwait()` or `pthread_cond_wait()`) by another thread results in **undefined behavior**.

Should be interpreted with the "results in undefined behavior" clause distributed over the "or" conjunction. In other words:

> Attempting to destroy a locked mutex results in **undefined behavior**.

and

> Attempting to destroy a mutex that is referenced (for example, while being used in a `pthread_cond_timedwait()` or `pthread_cond_wait()`) by another thread results in **undefined behavior**.

The second version is significant, because when waiting on the condition variable, the associated mutex lock is released by the waiting thread.